# How to change form element values in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this piece of simple code.

```
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText()
    {
       var form = document.forms['detail'];
       form.desc.value="success";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="detail">
    <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" >
    <input type="submit" value="changetext" onClick=changeText()>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run this in Mozilla browser the value of the textbox named "desc" changes but disappears immediately...i.e it is not shown forever and becomes empty.

How can I fix it.

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
<input type="submit" value="changetext" onClick="changeText(); return false;">
```

It looks like your page is refreshing, and that is probably why your field text disappears. If your `onClick` listener returns `false`, it will prevent this default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you can give that textbox an id

and then run document.getElementById("textboxid").value ="success";

that will work in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

The form gets submitted upon clicking the button that is typed as `"submit"` - the page gets reloaded.

Return `false` from the `changeText()` method and change `onClick=changeText()` to `onClick="return changeText();"` to prevent the form from getting submitted.

Alternatively, you can change the type of the button from `"submit"`to `"button"` to prevent submission. Then you'd have to add another submit button (even returning `false` will need you to find another way to submit the form).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" value="Name" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value='Name';" onclick="if(this.value == 'Name') this.value='';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> guy schaller

document.getElementById("textboxid").value ="success";

is good idea!

> vijayakumar-n

try to save    var form = document.forms['detail']; in a hidden input! then you will always be able to reach the form data..